# Removing Decimals from a list in python

Tags: python

I would like to know if it is possible to remove the decimals from a product of a maths command in python. My Code is below. I would like to print only the whole numbers and not show the others.

```
myList = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]
myInt = 7
newList = [x / myInt for x in myList]
print (newList)
```

Comment: `[x // myInt for x in myList if x % myInt == 0]`

Comment: I dont want to round it want to only output the whole divisible numbers for this case its 5.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that should be listed as an (the) answer, not a comment.

Comment: @9769953 I don't like low-hanging fruit. Besides, something like this has to be a duplicate if you look hard enough.

Comment: @JohnColeman it's not about points or the like, just to close off the question with an answer.

Comment: @9769953 Fair enough, but more seriously, I don't like to post an answer unless I am reasonably sure that it isn't a duplicate, and I suspect that most Python 1-liner answers are already duplicates.

Comment: @JohnColeman I would absolutely like to close this as a duplicate if possible, but quite often 1/ the duplicate is just off that, for a beginner, the similarity may be missed, and 2/ I've found it harder to find the correct duplicate than posting a one-line answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
newList = [x // myInt for x in myList if x % myInt == 0]
```

Comment: @BigSteve he's not. John indicated that he wasn't going to post as an answer. He's also flagged as community wiki so he won't get any reputation if it is upvoted. Having the answer posted allows you to accept it though and show that the issue is solved for you.

Comment: @BigSteve [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) includes "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it". I have no doubt that just about any sufficiently fluent Python programmer would come up with that exact line of code in seconds. I didn't really write it. In some sense -- Python wrote it for me.

Comment: @roganjosh What is 'he's flagged as community wiki' and why wouldn't get get points?

Comment: @VineethSai something of a relic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in newList: print(' %2.3f  '% i)
```